# Moving character on x axis

Tags: c#, unity

I am new to unity scripting.

I am trying to move my character towards right side(on x-axis) to create a running effect, I've imported the character from blender which contains two animations, "jump" and "run". What I want to do is I want my character to move on x-axis for which I've written following code

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(5f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
}
```

But I am facing one problem, if I set my character's y-axis rotation to 90 degrees in order to make him look towards right side I am getting strange results. That is, in play mode instead of moving towards right side(on x-axis) it move on x-axis and z-axis simultaneously & if I set the y-axis rotation to zero it behaves like I want it to. Please see the attached image for detail. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I have suggested that a moderator migrate this to Game Development.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Translate` overload, which takes `Space` [enumeration values](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Space.html), indicating, that shift is an absolute value, like:

```
transform.Translate(5f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f, Space.World);
```

or in more readable way

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 5f * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

`Vector3.left` returns a unit vector pointing left

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. And just like I thought, When Switching to my player model I had to change the movement direction from

```
transform.Translate(speed* Time.deltaTime,0,0);
```

to

```
transform.Translate(0,0,speed* Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: you don't need to switch direction after each rotation. Consider setting `Space.World` parameter